# Django: Upgrading to python3.6 with Amazon S3

Tags: django, python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto

I was running Django 1.11 with Python 3.5 and I decided to upgrade to Python 3.6.

Most things worked well, but I am having issues connection to AWS S3. I know that they have a new `boto` version `boto3` and that `django-storages` is a little outdated, so now there is `django-storages-redux`.

I've been trying multiple combinations of boto/boto3 and django-storages-redux/django-storages to see if it works. But I'm getting a lot of erros, from SSL connection failing to the whole website being offline due to server errors. The newest is my website throwing a `400 Bad Request` to all urls.

My app does run on Python 3.5, so I'm confident that the issue is around collectstatic and S3.

Is there anybody here who made a similar update work and tell me what configuration was used?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the issue.

Django-storages-redux was temporarily replacing django-storages since it's development had been interrupted.

Now the django-storages team restarted to support it.

That means that the correct configuration to use is: django-storages + boto3